# Unity3D. An image is invisible in my own "chat box", but only in "Play" mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I want to create a chat box. Messages should have a border. Also message could be located in one of two sides, I mean right or left side.
I have made two prefabs, one for left-side message and second one for right-side message.
When I add some prefab in chat box it works fine, I can see the border. But when I do it by the script, then the border is invisible.
Here is the structure.
[image]

The "Content" has Vertical Layout Group component with checked Width, and Content Size Fitter with Horizontal Fit - Unconstrained and Vertical Fit - Preferred Size.

The "Message left" has Horizontal Layout Group with unchecked Width and Height, and Layout Element with all unchecked.

The "Message (1)" has Content Size Fitter with Horizontal Fit - Unconstrained and Vertical Fit - Preferred Size, Horizontal Layout Group with Width checked, and Layout Element with Preferred Width - 291.5, and Flexible Width - 0.

Also here is two imaged, with border and without border.

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: The border is on "Message (1)" and it looks like [image]

So how do I fix it? Is there a solution?

UPDATE2: I have fixed it. The problem was in Z scaling of sprite, I set it to 0, but it has to be 1.

Comment: And what renderer supposed to draw that borders? I`m not very familiar with unity 5 gui, so I cant say if it is some custom part of your prefab or native gui component.

Comment: We would need to know where exactly this border sprite is located. Please give this info and check if you after instantiating set the scale to 1 (or whatever is proper for you)

Comment: of course I set the scaling to 1 and position to 0.

Comment: the border is on "Message (1)" and it looks like http://puu.sh/mAaou/ff6356a8eb.png

Comment: in Edit mode it works fine with any picture as border, but in Play mode nothing works, the picture just invisible

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Z scaling of sprite, I set it to 0, but it has to be 1.